# Euler class of extension of free nilpotent groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, nilpotent-groups

Fix some $n \geq 2$.  For $k \geq 1$, let $N_k$ be the free $k$-step nilpotent group on $n$ generators, i.e., the quotient of the free group $F_n$ by the $(k+1)^{\text{st}}$ term $\gamma_{k+1}(F_n)$ of its lower central series.  Let $\mathcal{L}_k = \gamma_k(F_n) / \gamma_{k+1}(F_n)$, so $\mathcal{L}_k$ is one of the graded terms of the free Lie algebra on $n$ generators.  Using Hopf's Formula, one sees that
$$H_2(N_k) \cong \mathcal{L}_{k+1}.$$
We also have a central extension
$$1 \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}_{k+1} \longrightarrow N_{k+1} \longrightarrow N_k \longrightarrow 1.$$
**Question**: How can I see that the Euler class of this extension is the identity element in
$$H^2(N_k;\mathcal{L}_{k+1}) = \text{Hom}(H_2(N_k);\mathcal{L}_{k+1}) = \text{Hom}(\mathcal{L}_{k+1},\mathcal{L}_{k+1}),$$
where the first equality follows from universal coefficients?

This is asserted without proof in the proof of Proposition 2.3 of

S. Morita, The extension of Johnson's homomorphism from the Torelli group to the mapping class group, Invent. Math. 111 (1993), no.1, 197-224.

All it says is that "we recall the well known fact that ...".

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457011/spectral-sequence-construction-of-euler-class-of-group-extension