# Spectral sequence construction of Euler class of group extension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be an abelian group equipped with an action of a group $G$ and let
$$1 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow \Gamma \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow 1$$
be an extension of group inducing the given action of $G$ on $A$.  This extension is classified by its Euler class $e \in H^2(G;A)$ (as defined in, say, Brown's book on group cohomology using a choice of a section $G \rightarrow \Gamma$ to define a 2-cocycle).

Here's another way to construct a natural element of $H^2(G;A)$.  Consider the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence of the extension with coefficients in $A$:
$$E_2^{pq} = H^p(G;H^q(A;A)) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(\Gamma;A).$$
In
$$E_2^{01} = H^0(G;H^1(A;A)) = \text{Hom}(A,A)^G,$$
we have the identity $\text{id}\colon A \rightarrow A$.  Let
$$d\colon E_2^{01} \rightarrow E_2^{20} = H^2(G;H^0(A;A)) = H^2(G;A)$$
be the differential, and define $e' = d(\text{id})$.

**Question**: Is it the case that $e = e'$?  Either a proof or a reference would be fine.

Comment: Yes, up to a sign. This is a special case of Theorem 4 on p. 133 of Hochschild—Serre‘s ‘Cohomology of group extensions‘.